# Unknown database in mysql dump on ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I am using mysqldump on ubuntu to take dump file of existing database

```
mysqldump -u username -h localhost -p databaseName > path/test.sql
```

But I am getting error as

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'databaseName' when selecting the database
```

and test.sql generates with following content

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.28, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: databaseName
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.04.1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Database exist but it is still showing Unknown database

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143294/discussion-on-question-by-hrishi-unknown-database-in-mysql-dump-on-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally its done with the help of suggetions by Jens.
Steps I followed are as

login to mariadb
using

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

and then

```
\! /opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u username -h localhost -p databaseName > path/test.sql
```